# How to send text message on mobile in php

Tags: php

How to send text Message using php code?
is there any free webservice for sending text message on mobile device in php?

Comment: Voted to close as Not Constructive as "this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion." But I use [Tropo](https://www.tropo.com/)

Comment: you are looking for free SMS API: http://stackoverflow.com/q/238579/669677

Answer (score 0):

You need a sms provider api. Like [Twillo](http://www.twilio.com/).

Comment: Thanks you Tapas
Twillo it free or not?

Comment: Yes it's free but there is some terms & condition. Check it out bro..